# Set localStorage or global variables before setting Gemini url

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, gemini

Is there a way to alter any global variable or localStorage item before loading the url specified in Gemini's setUrl?

I tried using executeJS but whatever I set is not available for the app initialization:

```
suite
  .setUrl( 'index.html' )
  .before( function( actions, find ) {
    actions.executeJS( function( window ) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'key', 'value' );
      navigator.language = 'sk';
      globalConfig.flag = true;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an [issue in gemini-testing](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/issues/799) addressing this usage.

Basically `setUrl()` needs to be called again after the values are set.